# Cannot find module in Jupyter Notebook but other python files can

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to use JupyterLab/Notebook within my API Service as a playground as I think it's a bit nicer than simply using the terminal. I've installed `jupyterlab` in my virtual environment and I believe it's activated according to the top right corner of the image uploaded. However, when I try to import a class I wrote, I get the error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'`

My current directory structure looks like this

```
/zen_api
  /api
  /playground
    test.ipynb <--- File getting the error
  /tests
```

I have other python files within my `tests` directory that `import api.*` which work fine so I'm wondering why my Notebook cannot find the module?

[image]

Comment: Install your packages or libraries using pip within a Jupyter Notebook. `!pip install package_name` run the following command in the notebook cell, replacing package_name with the name of the package you want to install

Comment: The package isn't a package I downloaded but rather a module I wrote locally. It's simply a class I want to import

Comment: @Asif , also please don't suggest practices where current better advice exists. Current best practice when running an installation from inside a modern Jupyter notebook is to use the magic install command. For `pip` that would be `%pip install` or for conda, `%conda install`. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about those commands. See [the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) to get a better sense ...

Comment: <continued> about how the exclamation point use with pip and conda can lead to issues and confusion. The magic variation of commands actually insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that underlies the active `.ipynb`. The exclamation point runs off in a temporary, separate shell instance, which may or may not be running where the kernel is.

Comment: I think you are leaving out some details we'd need to determine exactly what is happening. What is your working directory in your `.ipynb` file? Plus, in regards to why the Python files you mention in the post title work that you say are in the `tests` directory work, you tell us nothing about where Python is being run or what is your path that it is using, etc.. Without that specifically, I'll say the following: You want the notebook to be in the same directory as the api you are calling. Or at least switch the working directory in your active `.ipynb` using the magic `%cd` command to be ...

Comment: <continued> alongside the code that is specifying the api you are trying to call.